# Prefix a URL with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am pulling the content of a bunch of customer reviews from a website using a tiny piece of PHP, though the title of each review contains the URL to the original review on the website that it comes from, which is great, except that the URL that is pulled does not contain to originating websites full address.

So on my website, the link does not work. You can see it in action here:
http://www.clearpandb.co.uk/new2016/feedback.php try clicking one of the review titles.

Is there any way to fix this with CSS? I think all it needs is a prefix to the original site. What is pulled from the originating site is just e.g. "/job/view/1971050", which when clicked tries to find this on my site (obviously won't find it). So I need to prefix it with "www.mybuilder.com" so that it works.

If the above isn't possible, a last resort might be to just disable the URL (without removing the title text itself) just so that there isn't a bunch of broken links.

PHP being used:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = "https://www.mybuilder.com/profile/view/clear_plumbing_and_building_ltd/feedback";
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($target_url);
    foreach($html->find('li[class=job-view-feedback]') as $jobviewfeedback){    
                echo $jobviewfeedback;
                    }
                    ?>
```

I'm using a modified version of this tutorial for this:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-webcrawler-part-2
Which makes use of the a "helper" called "Simple HTML DOM".

Any help or pointers in the right direction are much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. Can you not add the base URL to the link in the HTML? And append the URL you are getting onto that?

Comment: This isn't something CSS does, but PHP or HTML can. Can you show us the PHP you're using to get the content?

Comment: hidanielle - I can't edit the HTML as it is all pulled directly from another website which I have no control over.

Comment: are you able to add JavaScript?

Comment: @jack I've copied the php code into the original comment as it seemed to mess up in the reply box.

Comment: @andi
I potentially could use js, though I'm not experienced with js and would prefer to avoid it if possible. Unless its a reasonably simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you edit that PHP?  If so, do a PHP string replace on $jobviewfeedback... search for `href="/` and replace with `href="http://www.mybuilder.com/`

so instead of

```
echo $jobviewfeedback;
```

you'd have

```
echo str_replace('href="/', 'href="http://www.mybuilder.com/', $jobviewfeedback);
```

Comment: I can edit the PHP, I'll give that a try now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, that has worked!!

Also extra thanks for providing the code snipet to use. I might have got there eventually but you certainly saved me a lot of time :)